# Flip a fair coin 5 times. $A$ is the event that the first flip is heads, and $B$ is the event that you get at least three heads. What is $P(A|B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to use the conditional probability formula, $P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. I've determined that $P(A)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(B)=\frac{1}{2^5}(\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5}) = \frac{1}{2}$, but I can't figure out how to solve for $P(A \cap B)$.

Comment: It is given that the first throw is  a head. How many ways are there to get at least $2$ heads in the next $4$ throws ?

Comment: Use Bayes formula : $P(A|B) = P(B|A)\frac{P(A)}{P(B)} $

Comment: @trueblueanil would it be something like $\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{4}$? And then divide by $2^4$?

Comment: @trueblueanil No; you are thinking of $\Pr[B \mid A]$, the probability of getting at least three heads given that the first flip is heads.  The question asks for the reverse, $\Pr[A \mid B]$, the probability that the first flip was heads, given you get at least three heads overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the event $B$, that you get at least three heads in five flips, there are $\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5}$ equiprobable such outcomes.  How many of these have heads in the first flip?  If there were exactly $3$ heads flipped and the first flip is heads, then there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to distribute the remaining $2$ heads and $2$ tails; if there are exactly $4$ heads flipped, there are $\binom{4}{1}$ ways to distribute the remaining $3$ heads and $1$ tail; and if $5$ heads are flipped there is only $1$ outcome.  So the desired probability is $$\frac{\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{1} + \binom{4}{0}}{\binom{5}{3} + \binom{5}{4} + \binom{5}{5}} = \frac{6+4+1}{10+5+1} = \frac{11}{16}.$$

---

The above is a pure enumeration approach.  We can consider a more general approach in which the probability of heads is some $p \in (0,1)$ rather than the fair case $p = 1/2$.  This is done by Bayes' theorem:
$$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[B \mid A]\Pr[A]}{\Pr[B]}.$$  The unconditional number of heads is a binomial random variable, $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 5, p), \\ \Pr[X = x] = \binom{5}{x} p^x (1-p)^{5-x},$$ hence event $B$ is equivalent to $X \ge 3$, and $$\Pr[B] = \Pr[X \ge 3] = \sum_{x=3}^5 \binom{5}{x} p^x (1-p)^{5-x}.$$  The conditional random variable $B \mid A$ corresponds to the outcome $Y \ge 2$ where $Y$ is binomial but with $n = 4$, because flips are independent; i.e. $$Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 4, p).$$  And of course, $\Pr[A] = p$.  So it follows that $$\Pr[A \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[Y \ge 2]p}{\Pr[X \ge 3]} = \frac{p \sum_{y=2}^4 \binom{4}{y} p^y (1-p)^{4-y}}{\sum_{x=3}^5 \binom{5}{x} p^x (1-p)^{5-x}} = \frac{6-8p+3p^2}{10-15p+6p^2}.$$  Note when $p = 1/2$ we recover the original answer $11/16$.

Answer (score 1):

**Flip a fair coin 5 times.  A  is the event that the first flip is heads, and  B  is the event that you get at least three heads. What is  P(A|B) ?**

For the event $(A\cap B)$ you need at least $2$ heads in the next $4$ tosses, thus

$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} = \dfrac {n(A\cap B)}{n(B)}$

$=\dfrac{\binom 4 2 + \binom 4 3 + \binom 4 4}{\binom 5 3 + \binom 5 4 + \binom 5 5} = \dfrac {11}{16}$

**PS**

If you want to use probabilities, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B|A)$, but you can further simplify the computation by dealing with number of ways rather than probabilities as shown above